# Dovecot config file missing

Tags: dovecot

I tried to install Dovecot and found some configuration files missing, which are, 10-auth.conf, 10-mail.conf, 10-master.conf and others. (It shows only 3 files - 90-quota.conf, 90-sieve.conf and 95-sni.conf in /etc/conf.d folder)

I used Debian 9 and Dovecot version is the newest version (1:2.2.27-3+deb9u7).

Below is my work.

I installed Dovecot by using ./build/dovecot and ./build dovecot_conf

I edit Mail settings in options.conf. (dovecot=yes and dovecot_conf=yes)

Tried to install by apt -y install dovecot-core dovecot-pop3d dovecot-imapd Result is

Reading state information... Done
dovecot-core is already the newest version (1:2.2.27-3+deb9u7).
dovecot-imapd is already the newest version (1:2.2.27-3+deb9u7).
dovecot-pop3d is already the newest version (1:2.2.27-3+deb9u7).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Dovecot status is active (running), but cannot login from Roundcube (It shows "Cannot connect IMAP server)

How can I solve this issue?

Regards,

Comment: is the /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf present?

Comment: Yes, there is dovecot.conf in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf.

Answer (score 1):

You could reinstall Dovecot with the default configuration files from the Debian packages using:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" \
  install --reinstall dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
```

If any configuration file gets replaced, the original will be saved with a `.dpkg-old` suffix. The behavior controlled by the `--force-confnew` is documented in man page [dpkg(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg.1.en.html).

Comment: It adds only 10-ssl.conf. Now, there are 4 files, which are, 10-ssl.conf, 90-quota.conf, 90-sieve.conf and 95-sni.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Thank, Esa Jokinen for your guideline.

After I tried to reinstall it, I found that some config cannot replace - "Not replacing deleted config file". Then, I search in Google and use the command below.

UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS=1 apt-get --reinstall install dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d